# C# programmatically add webcal:link in Outlook “internet calendar subscription”?

Tags: c#, outlook, calendar, webcal

I know how to add task programmatically into the outlook

- https://www.codeproject.com/articles/11097/sending-tasks-programmatically
- [How to add events to Outlook Calendar or Google Calendar programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18694607/5096993)

I am trying to add "webcal: link" programmatically into the outlook. But not getting any idea, it is possible to add "webcal: link" into the outlook for calendar sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

```
Outlook.Application ouApplication = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.Folder newFolder = ouApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI").OpenSharedFolder("webcalURL") as Outlook.Folder;
```