# JavaFX 8 create new Mail in Outlook

Tags: java, email, javafx, outlook

i would like to create a new email with Java respectively open the "New eMail" window from Outlook and insert some data (like CC, Body..)

I tried the SWT OLE Library, but that is a problem because i have a pure javafx8 application
next try was with

```
getHostServices().showDocument("mailto:a@b.c")
```

this works, but i can't format the text with html

Next try was the Desktop Class but same problem like getHostServices, no html formatted emails.

Some ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook is a COM server which you can automate using the OLE COM technology. I don't use Java for developing, but I hope you will find how to call the COM servers in Java, for example - [Is there OLE Automation in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679810/is-there-ole-automation-in-java). See [Using Automation to Send a Microsoft Outlook Message](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/161088). It shows you how to use Automation to create and send a Microsoft Outlook message.

Also you may find the [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/201096?wa=wsignin1.0) article helpful.